# Как из manytomany field получить связанные объекты

Tags: python, django

Всем привет! Я новичок в django, прочитал доку, посмотрел примеры, но не знаю, как выполнить задачу.
У меня есть модель event.models.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.signals import post_save, post_delete
from team.models import Team
from accounts.models import CustomUser
from django.utils.encoding import python_2_unicode_compatible
from django.dispatch import receiver

@python_2_unicode_compatible
class Fight(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(u'название', max_length=255)
    description = models.TextField(u'описание', max_length=2000, blank=True)
    team_1 = models.ForeignKey(Team, verbose_name=u'команда 1', related_name='first_team', blank=True, null=True)
    players_1 = models.ManyToManyField(CustomUser, verbose_name=u'игроки первой команды', related_name='first_team_players')
    team_2 = models.ForeignKey(Team, verbose_name=u'команда 2', related_name='second_team', null=True)
    players_2 = models.ManyToManyField(CustomUser, verbose_name=u'игроки второй команды', related_name='second_team_players')
    time = models.DateTimeField(u'время', auto_now_add=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
    return self.title

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'поединок'
        verbose_name_plural = 'поединки'

def team_recount(team):
    count = Fight.objects.filter(team_1=team).count() + Fight.objects.filter(team_2=team).count()
    team.games_done = count
    team.save()

def players_recount(instance):
    #users_related = CustomUser.objects.filter(Fight=instance)

@receiver(post_delete, sender = Fight)
@receiver(post_save, sender = Fight)
def signal_catched(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    first_team = instance.team_1
    second_team = instance.team_2
    team_recount(first_team)
    team_recount(second_team)
    players_recount(instance)
```

Нужно, чтобы, при создании или удалении поединка, по сигналу, производился перерасчет количества проведенных поединков для команд(работает) и присутствовавших игроков. Для игроков все упирается в то, как из Fight instance из manytomany field получить CustomUserов.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все до безобразия просто

```
players_1_list = instance.players_1.all()
```

получаем список CustomUserов и для каждого делаем перерасчет, как с командами

Answer (score 0):

Не забывайте использовать [prefetch_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.prefetch_related) и также [select_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) так как если их не использовать то во втором цикле у Вас будет на каждую запись новый запрос к базе.

```
for i in Fight.objects.all().prefetch_related('players_1'):
    for j in i.players_1.all():
        print(j)
```

Comment: В первой строке должно быть опечатка. `for*`

Comment: @Egor Trutnev Да, спасибо, поправил. Столкнулся тут кстати с такой проблемой, увидишь где то мелкую опечатку поправишь, а тебе пишут что нужно вносить правку не менее столько то символов, что оказалось неудобно.